# Google Calendar API - Automatically Identify Events from a String (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, api, google-calendar-api

I've looked through other questions but i don't think this has been asked before:

I have an email client i'm building in the .NET framework, and would like to automatically create google calendar events (just like in gmail). Is there a way to feed an email message (i.e. a string) and automatically identify if there is a possible event or not in that?

Any ideas?

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can if you do the parsing of the email yourself. If you make up your own format and use that in emails from and to yourself. With the Google Api you can create an event based on the parsed event.

1. Receive email
2. Parse new email for possible events (look up if your specified string occurs in the mail)
3. Create event in Google based on found events

Comment: Is there a way to automatically identify events like in Gmail though?